# Installing Redmine version 2.0.2 on Dreamhost shared hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, dreamhost

I tried following the [dreamhost documentation](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Redmine) (which is for Redmine 1.x and last edited about a year ago) and the [redmine install documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) as much as possible.

I am trying to install version 2.0.2 which I pulled down using

```
hg clone --updaterev 2.0-stable https://bitbucket.org/redmine/redmine-all
```

I used [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to get a local version of Ruby 1.9.3 in order to install the appropriate dependencies.  It seemed to go pretty well until I got to the last step where I had to load it in a browser.  I got an error from Passenger stating that the application could not be started.  It read:

> The application has exited during startup (i.e. during the evaluation
>   of config/environment.rb). The error message may have been written to
>   the web server's log file. Please check the web server's log file
>   (i.e. not the (Rails) application's log file) to find out why the
>   application exited. If that doesn't help, then please use the
>   backtrace below to debug the problem.

I couldn't find anything useful in the logs (couldn't even find the place it err'd - perhaps I was looking in the wrong place? `/home/username/logs/my.site.com/http`)

The backtrace looks like it is a dependency error, but it looked pretty generic.

The command I used to install the proper gems was: (I'm using mysql)

```
$ bundle install --without development test postgresql sqlite rmagick
```

Running `bundle show` in my web directory gives me this:

```
~/my.site.com$ bundle show
Gems included by the bundle:
  * actionmailer (3.2.5)
  * actionpack (3.2.5)
  * activemodel (3.2.5)
  * activerecord (3.2.5)
  * activeresource (3.2.5)
  * activesupport (3.2.5)
  * arel (3.0.2)
  * builder (3.0.0)
  * bundler (1.1.4)
  * coderay (1.0.6)
  * erubis (2.7.0)
  * hike (1.2.1)
  * i18n (0.6.0)
  * journey (1.0.4)
  * json (1.7.3)
  * mail (2.4.4)
  * mime-types (1.18)
  * multi_json (1.3.6)
  * mysql2 (0.3.11)
  * net-ldap (0.3.1)
  * polyglot (0.3.3)
  * prototype-rails (3.2.1)
  * rack (1.4.1)
  * rack-cache (1.2)
  * rack-openid (1.3.1)
  * rack-ssl (1.3.2)
  * rack-test (0.6.1)
  * rails (3.2.5)
  * railties (3.2.5)
  * rake (0.9.2.2)
  * rdoc (3.12)
  * ruby-openid (2.1.8)
  * sprockets (2.1.3)
  * thor (0.15.2)
  * tilt (1.3.3)
  * treetop (1.4.10)
  * tzinfo (0.3.33)
```

Here are my executable versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.5
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.1.4
$ gem -v
1.8.24
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Here's the backtrace.

```
#   File    Line    Location
0   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb  10  in `exit'
1   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb  10  
2   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    36  in `gem_original_require'
3   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    36  in `require'
4   /home/username/site.com/config/boot.rb  6   
5   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
6   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
7   /home/username/site.com/config/application.rb   1   
8   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
9   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
10  /home/username/site.com/config/environment.rb   2   
11  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
12  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
13  config.ru   3   
14  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `instance_eval'
15  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `initialize'
16  config.ru   1   in `new'
17  config.ru
```

Comment: "The backtrace looks like it is a dependency error, but it looked pretty generic." Paste it anyway.

Comment: I noticed that your "bundle -v" output shows version 1.1.4, but your backtrace shows a path with 1.0.7.  FWIW, I'm running Redmine 1.2.1 on DH shared hosting.  I don't remember having to install anything too special to get it working, I believe I'm using the default ruby (1.8.7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the system's ruby 1.8 instead of using rvm and ruby 1.9.

Don't use passenger on Dreamhost.  Dreamhost's passenger is old (v2.2.9) and will only load an old version of rack and will randomly wipe environment variables causing your site to occasionally not load.

Use FCGI instead.  Add the `fcgi` gem to your Gemfile

```
gem "fcgi"
```

Create a `dispatch.fcgi` file at `~/foo.yourdomain.com/public/dispatch.fcgi` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# Set necessary environment variables
ENV['HOME'] ||= `echo ~`.strip
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems')
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.expand_path('~/.gems') + ":" + '/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8'

#require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
#require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'
require '/home/user/programs/redmine-2.0.3/config/boot'
require '/home/user/programs/redmine-2.0.3/config/environment'

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
    parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
    env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
    env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(RedmineApp::Application)
```

To restart your app, you have to manually kill the `dispatch.fcgi` process or else your changes won't have any effect

```
pkill dispatch.fcgi
```